# Remove trailing zero from web3.toAscii() conversion

Tags: web3js, truffle, javascript, testing

I have a contract that returns a bytes32 type variable and I'm currently testing it with truffle and javascript. 
The original data

```
['Roberto', 'Juan', 'Andrea']
```

This array is what i get as a response from my contract:

```
[ '0x526f626572746f00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
  '0x4a75616e00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
  '0x416e647265610000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000' ]
```

And this my code

```
let cands = [];
let length = Number(await voting.candidateListLength());
for (let i = 0; i < length; i++)
    cands.push(web3.toAscii(await voting.candidateList(i)));
console.log(cands);
```

Using web3.toAscii() method on each element to a obtain a human-friendly string produces the following:

```
[ 'Roberto\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000',
  'Juan\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000',
  'Andrea\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000' ]
```

Is there a way to remove the extra characters that come along with the original data?

Comment: Why does it return `bytes32` and not `string`? (in which case, you could simply get rid of the `web3.toAscii` on the client side).

Comment: because between contracts strings cannot be returned, and i'm trying to find a way to pass data that can be represented as strings for the end user of my Dapp

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`web3.toUtf8()` will do the magic for you

Comment: is that used in which web3 version?

Comment: I used this for web3 0.20.1, for web3 1.0.0-beta.26 using web3.utils.hexToUtf8 solved it

Answer (score 2):

The `web3.toAscii` will not do that for you. This is the original code ([ref](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/blob/develop/lib/utils/utils.js#L128)):

```
var str = "";
var i = 0, l = hex.length;
if (hex.substring(0, 2) === '0x') {
  i = 2;
}
for (; i < l; i+=2) {
  var code = parseInt(hex.substr(i, 2), 16);
  str += String.fromCharCode(code);
}
```

but nobody stops you to create your own function to prevent this behavior. Example:

```
function toAscii(hex) {
  var str = "";
  var i = 0, l = hex.length;
  if (hex.substring(0, 2) === '0x') {
    i = 2;
  }
  for (; i < l; i+=2) {
    var code = parseInt(hex.substr(i, 2), 16);
    if(code != 0) {
      str += String.fromCharCode(code);
    }
  }

  return str;
}
```

web3 1.0 should fix this issue [ref](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/blob/1.0/packages/web3-utils/src/utils.js#L195) using `web3.utils.hexToUtf8`

Comment: So i would export this and then use within my other files, right?

Comment: or you use web3 1.0 that has this function `web3.utils.hexToUtf8`